# When i press run button it shows no compatible devices found

Tags: android, demo

i am following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html. i downloaded Demo Activity-lifecycle from here . when i press run->Android-Application it shows NO COMPATIBLE TARGETS WERE FOUND. i downloaded Android4.2 and Android 2.2 from SDK snd avd manager. i created four AVD using android4.2 and android2.2 but it shows No compatible devices found. can anyone tell me which device is compatible with Activity-lifecycle.

with regards

ajay

Comment: what is the minsdk or target sdkversion you have set in android manifest file.

Comment: You said _i created AVD using android4.2 and android2.2_. Then you started the AVD's.?

Comment: these are android min.sdk =07 and and target sdk version=15 respectively

Comment: console shows "Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch" min. sdk is 7 i am using 8(FROYO) to run the application but it still not works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already created Specific AVDs then follow this steps

```
Right click on your android project->Run Configuration-> in target tab select-> always prompt to pick device
```

Then run your project and it will show you all online as well as offline AVD's ,so now select AVD from this list. it will start that AVD and run your application.

**Update**

> "Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch"

Have you created those AVDs by setting target as `Google-API` ? if not then edit your AVD and set target to `Google-Api` and run again

Comment: console shows "Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch" min. sdk is 7 i am using 8(FROYO) still not works?

Answer (score 0):

Create **AVD** that supports android-17 **(Android 4.2)** or android-8 **(Android-2.2)**.

How to create new AVD ?

```
on Eclipse, [Window> Android AVD Manager] select,

you press the [new] button, you can create new Android Virtual Device
```

Comment: hey i tried that thing earlier but not works. do you know which AVD is compatible with Activity Lifecycle?

Comment: dear, AVD selection and creation is depends on the API level on which your application is working. Do not misguide yourself. Create an AVD of API, of which your application is prepared.

Comment: hey  minsdk given is 7 and target sdk given is 15 so i changed the target and min sdk to 17 and 8 respectively then i press i run->android application but still it won't works. don't know what to do?

Comment: console shows "Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch" min. sdk is 7 i am using 8(FROYO) still not works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a compatible AVD created in accordance with your app's target.
*An AVD and the target mentioned for your specific application should match.

If the AVD is not yet created, follow these steps:

```
on Eclipse, [Window> Android AVD Manager] select NEW,  
(press the [new] button), you can create new Android Virtual Device
```

Or the most easiest way is to go for a fresh install of Eclipse which has built-in Android SDK. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. 
I created new data definitions(i.e Eclipse---->Window--->AVD Manager--->Data Definitions). Add the data definitions corresponding the android version you selected as the target while creating the application.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
I have the same problem with a proyect that it uses Google Apis, in the AVD Manager I create a new, and change the Target to Google Api 16 and It works

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.
my solution was to simply re-install the SDK.